# Path connectedness of the complement of a null set

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and $A\subset D$ such that $\pi_i(A)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue null set for $1\leq i\leq n$. For $x,y\in D\setminus A$, is there a rectifiable path $p$ connecting x,y? With length $\leq |x-y|+\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Not only does it look like homework, but it is completely incomprehensible, to boot...

Comment: It seems clear to me, just a bit laconic as to the style. $\pi_i(A)$ is the projection of $A$ on the $i$-th coordinate (not an homotopy group). 

Comment: Is $\pi_i(A)$ a projection to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ or to $\mathbb{R}$?  The former would suggest (but not prove, IIRC) that $\dim(A)<n-1$, and the latter that $\dim(A)<1$ (where $\dim(A)$ is the Hausdorff dimension).  I think it is known that $D\setminus A$ is path-connected if $\dim(A)<n-1$. 